# LINQ C# building an expression with anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

I have `BinaryTree<Student>` DeserializedStudents
and linq query:

```
var students = DeserializedStudents.OrderBy(testResult => testResult.Test_Result).
Select(cust => new { name = cust.Name, result = cust.Test_Result });
```

Can someone please tell me how to build an expression that is equal to this query?

Comment: Define *expression*? Also where is `cust` coming from?

Comment: He is probably talking about [LINQ Query Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

With complex expressions, you can cheat and see what the compiler does:

```
Expression<Func<IEnumerable<Student>, IEnumerable<Student>>> expression = 
  query => query
    .OrderBy(testResult => testResult.Test_Result)
    .Select(cust => new { name = cust.Name, result = cust.Test_Result });
```

Just have a look at `expression` in a debugger.

BTW, [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) is very helpful for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IQueryable` interface implementation to auto-build your expression based on `LinQ`:

```
var query = DeserializedStudents.AsQueryable()
    .OrderBy(testResult => testResult.Test_Result)
    .Select(cust => new { name = cust.Name, result = cust.Test_Result });

var expression = query.Expression;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?:

```
var students = from cust in DeserializedStudents
               orderby cust.Test_Result
               select new { name = cust.name, result = cust.Test_Result };
```